# What is this weird splotchy dust growing under my table?

Tags: cleaning

I store a little swivel desk stool underneath my ping-pong table in the basement and I noticed one day that the cloth on the chair looked like it had round water stains. I then folded the table sides up and witnessed a constellation of dust on the underside (on both sides).

Photos:

[image: Image 1/4]

[image: Image 2/4]

[image: Image 3/4]

[image: Image 4/4]

I took several paper towels and cleaned it off. After cleaning, a faint imprint remains. It kind of has the consistency of spider webs. The dust invariably grows back in a few weeks.

I am simply curious as to what this is, because I've never seen dust in clusters like this (as opposed to a thin, uniform layer). I hope it is not mold or fungus. The room is relatively clean and I can't find this dust anywhere else in the room or under other tables. Why the ping-pong table?

Comment: What's the table made of? MDF? particle board? Does it get damp in the room it's in?

Comment: @Comintern -- I think the table is not "real" wood, but I can't tell the difference between MDF and particle board. It does not get physically wet but it is in a basement so I assume there's more moisture in the air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check for sources of water leakage or excessive humidity in the room it appears to be some sort of mold and based on what you told me about what led to its appearance it sounds even more like some kind of mold.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I always thought mold smelled bad, but this stuff doesn't have an odor. There used to be a dehumidifier right next to the table but I moved it to the next room over a few months ago. I might bring it back and see if it helps. I just noticed the mold recently so I don't know if the dehumidifier prevented the mold growth. I still wonder why only the ping-pong table has mold.

Comment: Taking moisture out of the air would certainly dissuade mold growth. Mold may not always smell like you might think it might smell. A large bit of it will leave a musty smell in the room without necessarily having a pinpoint bad smell. Scrape a little bit of it off put it on a plate, put a little bleach on it, see what happens. The bleach will instantly destroy it. Of course bleach will instantly destroy almost any small fibrous tissue but it might render some clues. My gut feeling tells me its mold.. I've seen the same type thing in a somewhat different situation before and it was mold. As fo

Comment: I will try the bleach experiment. What am I looking for? Also, it seems your comment was cut short.

Comment: It should dissolve completely. I don't know why that comment was cut off earlier I guess I might have reached the maximum number of words or characters. I am new to stack Exchange so I do not know what the limitations are. The only thing that I was going to say on that comment was I don't know why the mold is specifically on the ping pong table either I will have to check that one out myself. Has the ping pong table ever been water log or exposed to a damp area for a long period of time?

Comment: No on both counts. The only thing I can think of is what @Comintern mentioned above...the table is made of some sort of particle board, and it is "rough" on the underside...which maybe allows moisture to permeate into the wood, and eventually forms these spores?